# How to rotate virtual camera using mouse input with unity's new Input System?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am devoloping a game with using unity New Input Sytem and I am using Character Controller for move my character. I want to rotate my virtual camera(it's third person camera) on all axis while drag my mouse on screen but i couldn't find a way how to do that simple task.